# How to get the extract the Time zone from systemTimeZone

Tags: ios

i have added the sample along with this.

```
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSLog(@"%@",[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]);
```

i am getting   time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30) offset 19800, repeat interval = 0

see the below image

i want to set remainder jan 28 4.30 pm  but it stored 11:05:34 time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30) offset 19800

see tableview cell

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by exact?

Comment: Whats wrong with it! You need some other place's timezone..eh?

Comment: yes, i want set india time zone

Comment: "**Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30) offset 19800**" is the time zone of India dude!!

Comment: thanks , i have attached app screenshot please refer i want set exact time 04:35:34

Answer (score 1):

With

> NSTimeZone *localTime = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

you're getting the timezone that's set on the device.

Here's the documentation of `NSTimeZone`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Use the object like this:

> NSLog(@"Current local timezone  is  %@ (%d seconds from GMT)", [localTime name], [localTime secondsFromGMT]);